RTL language issue in SwiftUI
I have issue in SwiftUI with Right to Left Languages (Arabic)
The navigation bar is correct, but check the list row and text editor, its flipped to the left edge, which it must be in the right edge in Arabic, the default language in project file, is Arabic, also the built in options menu for the search bar is flipped
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var text: String = "تجريبي"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
                
            
            List {
                Section {
                    Text("مرحبا")
                    
                    TextEditor(text: self.$text)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("جديد")
        }
        .searchable(text: self.$searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
    }
}

Screen1
Screen2
sample project
The list content should start appearing from right edge, also the search bar options menu should be flipped

I solved the problem in List by adding this code:
@Environment(\.layoutDirection) private var layoutDirection

List {
    // text views …  
}
.scaleEffect(x: self.layoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? -1 : 1)

But the issue on the search bar menu options remains unsolved.
